# using dynamic_cast for runtime type identification

Tags: c++, dynamic-cast, static-cast

when reading Essential c++ chapter 5.10 Run-time Type identification, I've encountered a problem. Let me introduce a little background first. There are a base class named `num_sequence` and a class `Fibonacci` derive from `num_sequence`. In the base class, there is a virtual function named `gen_elems` and the derived class has its own definition.

The following comes from the book.

```
Fibonacci fib;
num_sequence *ps = &fib;
ps->gen_elems(64);
```

> We know that the Fibonacci instance of gen_elems() will be invoked.
>   However, although we know from this test that ps addresses a Fibonacci
>   class object, an attempt to invoke the Fibonacci instance of
>   gen_elems() directly through ps results in a compile-time error:
>
> ps->Fibonacci::gen_elems(64); //gives compile-time error
>
> ps does not know the type of the object it addresses, even if we and the typeid and virtual function mechanisms do.
>
> **To invoke the Fibonacci instance of gen_elems(), we must instruct the compiler to convert `ps` into a pointer of type Fibonacci.** The static_cast and dynamic_cast can both do this job.

I'm confused by the bold sentence. `ps->gen_elems(64)` actually invokes the Fibonacci instance of `gen_elems()`. Why need we use static_cast and dynamic_cast to convert it to a pointer of type Fibonacci?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under **most** situations, you would just call the virtual method normally and let polymorphism do its work to call the most-derived implementation as needed.  What the author is trying to explain is that it is also possible to directly call a **specific** implementation of a virtual method without going through polymorphism.

Say a class derives from `Fibonacci` to override `gen_elems()` again, but you do not want to call that override, you want to call the `Fibonacci` override.  By converting a `num_sequence` pointer into a `Fibonacci` pointer (or descendant pointer) at compile-time, it allows the compiler to access the `Fiboncci` vtable so it can emit code to directly call `Fibonacci::gen_elems()` (if the object being pointed at during run-time is not actually an instance of `Fibanocci` or descendant, you will likely crash/corrupt your app. That cannot be validated at compile-time).

For example:

```
class num_sequence
{
public:
    virtual void gen_elems(int value)
    {
        std::cout << "num_sequence" << std::endl;
    }
};

class Fibonacci : public num_sequence
{
public:
  void gen_elems(int value)
  {
        std::cout << "Fibonacci" << std::endl;
  }
};

class SomethingElse : public Fibonacci
{
public:
  void gen_elems(int value)
  {
        std::cout << "SomethingElse" << std::endl;
  }
};
```

.

```
num_sequence ns;
Fibonacci fib;
SomethingElse se;
num_sequence *ps;

ps = &ns;
ps->gen_elems(64); // displays "num_sequence"

ps = &fib;
ps->gen_elems(64); // displays "Fibonacci"

ps = &se;
ps->gen_elems(64); // displays "SomethingElse"

ps->Fiboacci::gen_elems(64); // compiler error!

static_cast<Fibonacci*>(ps)->Fibonacci::gen_elems(64); // displays "Fibonacci"
static_cast<SomethingElse*>(ps)->Fibonacci::gen_elems(64); // displays "Fibonacci"

Fibonacci *pfib = dynamic_cast<Fibonacci*>(ps);
if (pfib != NULL)
{
    pfib->gen_elems(64); // displays "SomethingElse"
    pfib->Fibonacci::gen_elems(64); // displays "Fibonacci"
}
```

Comment: Upvoted because Remy is right, but I wish I could downvote Lippman (the author of Essential C++). The short answer is "If you aren't a beginner, you might want to do [some fairly arcane thing.]" He should have known not to introduce this stuff here, and I'm surprised he did, since generally his stuff is great.